# Find duplicate ID and add new sequence ID

Tags: sql, duplicates, sequence

I have a table where ID must be unique. There are some IDs that are not unique. How do I generate a new column which adds a sequence to this ID? I want to generate ID_new_generated in the table below

```
ID Company Name ID_new_generated
1  A            1
1  B            1_2
2  C            2
```

Comment: Do you not use constraint like `primary key` or `unique` in the id column? I think it would be better fix the data rather do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a windowing function (e.g. Rank) to to generate an secondary ID, over each window defined by rows that have the same ID number, then just concatenate it to create the new one.

something like:

```
select 
    ID
    , companyName
    , rank() over(partition by ID ORDER BY companyName)
    , concat(ID, '_',  rank() over(partition by ID ORDER BY companyName)) as new_id
from test;
```

See this demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bd6aQKnZ7gcZCQjFpZicrp/0

Syntax will be different depending on which sql you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you are looking for a solution in SQL Server:

First you will need to add a nullable column ID_Generated like below:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD COLUMN ID_Generated varchar(25) null
GO
```

Then, use row_number like below in a cte structure (you can use temp table if you are using mysql):

```
;with cte as (
   SELECT DISTINCT t.ID,  
                   (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.ID order by t.ID)) as RowNumber
   FROM tablename t
   INNER JOIN (select ID, Count(*) RecCount
               From tablename
               group by ID
               having Count(*) > 1) tt on t.ID = t.ID 
   ORDER BY id ASC
)
Update t
set t.ID_Generated = cte.RowNumber
from tablename t
inner join cte on t.ID = cte.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select ID, companyName,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by companyname) = 1
             then cast(id as varchar(255))
             else id || '_'  || row_number() over (partition by id order by companyname)
        end) as new_id
from test;
```

`||` is the ANSI/ISO standard concatenation operator in SQL.  Not all databases support it, so you might need to replace the operator with the one appropriate for your database.